# Trouble getting D3-generated SVG to appear on screen consistently

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm currently working on a Javascript project where I am trying to render the following chart using d3.

[image: chart sample]

The problem, though is that sometimes svg elements for the yellow chart fails to show sometimes (and at random). The problem usually goes away after I refresh the page (once or multiple times). When this happens, the browser dev tools still show that the svg elements are present:

[image: browser window]

This only happens to the yellow chart and never to the blue chart.

This is the function that I used to create the chart:

```
function makeGraphs(filterDisease,filterAir) {
var width = 840;
var height = 110;
var barPadding = 1;

var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0,width-50]);

var yScaleDisease = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height,0]);

var yScaleAir = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0,height]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("top");

var yAxisDisease = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScaleDisease)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxisAir = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScaleAir)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var svgDisease = d3.select("body").select("#comparison-chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class","chart-comparison")
    .attr("id","chart-comparison-disease")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height);

var svgAir = d3.select("body").select("#comparison-chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "chart-comparison")
    .attr("id", "chart-comparison-air")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height + 20);

d3.json("/datasets/disease", function(error, datasetDisease) {
    datasetDisease.forEach(function(d) {
        d["date"] = dateFormat.parse(d["date"]);
        d["total"] = 0
        for (i=0;i<filterDisease.length;i++) {
            d["total"] += d[filterDisease[i]];
        }
    });

    var ndxDisease = crossfilter(datasetDisease);
    var dateDimDisease = ndxDisease.dimension(function(d) {return d["date"];});
    var total_disease = dateDimDisease.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d["total"];});

    var datasetDisease_formatted = total_disease.all();

    xScale.domain([new Date(datasetDisease_formatted[0]["key"]), new Date(datasetDisease_formatted[datasetDisease_formatted.length -1]["key"])]);
    yScaleDisease.domain([0,d3.max(datasetDisease_formatted,function(d) {return d["value"];})]);

    svgDisease.selectAll("rect")
        .data(datasetDisease_formatted)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(new Date(d["key"]));})
        .attr("y", function(d) { return yScaleDisease(d["value"]); })
        .attr("width", (width-50)/datasetDisease_formatted.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return height - yScaleDisease(d["value"]);
        })
        .attr("fill", "#19C3CD")
        .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)");

    svgDisease.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
        .call(yAxisDisease);

    svgDisease.append("text")
        .text("Disease Records")
        .attr("x", 650)
        .attr("y", 20);

});

d3.json("/datasets/air", function(error, datasetAir) {
    datasetAir.forEach(function(d) {
        d["date"] = dateFormat.parse(d["date"]);
        d["total"] = 0
        for (i=0;i<filterAir.length;i++) {
            d["total"] += d[filterAir[i]];
        }
    });

    var ndxAir = crossfilter(datasetAir);
    var dateDimAir = ndxAir.dimension(function(d) {return d["date"];});
    var total_pollutants = dateDimAir.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d["total"];});

    var datasetAir_formatted = total_pollutants.all();

    yScaleAir.domain([0, d3.max(datasetAir_formatted, function(d) {return d["value"];})])

    svgAir.selectAll("rect")
        .data(datasetAir_formatted)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(new Date(d["key"]));})
        .attr("y",0)
        .attr("width", (width-50)/datasetAir_formatted.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return yScaleAir(d["value"]);
        })
        .attr("fill", "#FED40A")
        .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)");

    svgAir.append("g")
        .attr("class","x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(50," + (height+20) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svgAir.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
        .call(yAxisAir);

    svgAir.append("text")
        .text("Air Pollutant")
        .attr("x", 650)
        .attr("y", 90);
});
};
```

Is there any problem with my code that is causing this issue? Oh, and I'm using crossfilter as well to format my JSON data.

Comment: I presume its a crossfilter issue bringing back empty datasets maybe ?

Comment: I don't believe that's it... I just added a console.log statement at the end of the code to return the crossfilter data - the data was present. Besides, if that were the case, the height and width of the svg elements should have been rendered as '0' or 'NaN' because I used the data to calculate these attributes.